# Did Kauravas end in Heaven after death?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas, kauravas

After Mahabharata war, where did the Kauravas and Pandavas end after death. Heaven or Hell?

Comment: @Keshav did all Kauravas go to heaven?

Comment: @AnilKumar Yes, they did; see this chapter of the Swargarohanika Parva of the Mahabharata: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18005.htm "The sons of Dhritarashtra were all Rakshasas of fierce might. Sanctified by death caused by weapons, those high-souled beings of prosperity all succeeded in attaining to Heaven."